# Does libc++ maintain an internal state?

Tags: c++, stl, libc++

Does libc++ maintain a process-wide internal state where actions occuring in one part of the code can affect some distant part of the code through calls to std::* classes (e.g. std::set)?  To be a bit more specific I've seen crashes such as this (showing top of stack trace only):

`std::__1::__tree<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::__insert_unique(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 156, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

where the fix was to upgrade a library not directly involved in the crash, to correct for a C++ ABI issue.  I'm just surprised an ABI issue could have an effect so far from the cause, and wondering if the standard library itself is having some state corrupted?

Comment: The global `operator new` and `operator delete` maintain a per-process heap. They're used by `std::allocator`, and so (by default) by any standard class that allocates memory, and seem to be implicated here. Corrupting the heap could break any other code that uses it.

Comment: Errors with `std::__1` usually mean you are using LLVM's **libc++**, not GNU's **libstdc++**.

Comment: @Macmade Good point let me re-arrange my question in a moment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ doesn't offer a protected environment. If any part of the code does something forbidden (e.g. deleting an object twice, writing off the limits of an array ...) then any other place of the code can do anything, either immediately or after a long time.

Actually often the problem is that errors just don't apparently cause any harm as the program (apparently) simply works.

An error about a violation of the ABI is very low level (for example the machine code could be required to preserve a certain register and it doesn't) and there's nothing you can be surprised about. Welcome to "undefined behavior" hell.

In the specific `std::set` and `std::map` in certain implementations are known to depend on sentinels, so overwriting a global variable can affect even maps and sets created later.

Also almost everything in C++ depends on dynamically allocated memory and a program violating the ABI can corrupt the data structures related to that and the effects can manifest millions of executed instructions later (when for example that corrupted free block gets reallocated for something else).